# Local variables adresses in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I have this little Program:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {

    char a;
    char b;

    printf("Adress a: %p\n", (void *)&a);
    printf("Adress b: %p\n", (void *)&b);

    return 0;
}
```

The adress of b is lower, than the adress of b. Why is it like this? Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably because the stack grows downwards, although I don't see the point of this question.

Comment: I guess it has to do with how your compiler (or ur OS) allocates memory. Some stacks have higher base address which decrease as we move up the stack , whereas as some start with a lower one and go higher. It shouldn't be a concern and neither is it an error.

Comment: @John3136: Because he/she is curious!

Comment: It is definitely not wrong! Just an implementation detail :)

Comment: Anyway be aware that regardless of what direction the stack expands, the compiler can reorder local variables however it likes. For example, if you declared `int a; char b; int c; char d; int e;` and `int` is 4-aligned then it could save a little space by putting the `char` variables next to each other. So you shouldn't be surprised by whatever order variables appear on the stack. In some situations the same location can be used for two different variables, although taking their addresses tends to obstruct that potential optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storage space for a local variable is on the stack. The X86 processor family has a stack which "grows downward". This means that as allocations occur (for example assigning a variable), the stack pointer is moved downwards toward lower memory addresses.

`&a` is greater than `&b` because after `&a` was assigned, the stack pointer was moved downward to a lower address for the next allocation.

Comment: "after &a was assigned, the stack pointer was moved downward to a lower address for the next allocation." -- you can think of it this way, but that's probably not what the compiler actually did. Probably it emitted code to move the stack pointer once on function entry.

Comment: Point taken, my answer does not represent the action likely to be taken by an actual compiler. When I first began learning about the low level implementation of functions, it was easier to grasp the concept this way, and then figure out what was being optimized.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the stack grows down.

`a` and `b` are allocated on the stack in order of definition. So you have that `&a` is higher than `&b`.